# Run a python code only when a specific object appears in screen

Tags: python, automation, screen, pyautogui

In the following image, I want Python (using module Pyautogui) to click the "OK" button.

[image]

The problem is, I dont know when the "OK" button appears. So how do I make python to click the "OK" button only when it appears?

**References**:

If you wonder it looks like a mobile screen, I am using an android emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyAutoGUI has a function called `locateOnScreen()` which takes a screenshot of your current screen and then looks for the provided image you pass into the parameter of the function.

First, you need to have a picture of the "OK" button to tell PyAutoGUI what to look for, which you can do using `pyautogui.screenshot('ok.png', region=(0, 0, 300, 400))` the region parameter specifies where to look and the size of the picture.

After that, you can run `locateOnScreen('ok.png')` and if the picture 'ok.png' is currently on your monitor it will return the center coordinates, which you can then pass to `pyautogui.click()`

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.screenshot('ok.png', region=(0, 0, 300, 400))
```

Run that line of code and play around with the `region` parameter until you get a good looking 'ok.png' and make sure only the button is visible in the picture as PyAutoGUI looks for an **exact** match. Once you're done, replace the line with the following:

```
import pyautogui

location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ok.png')

pyautogui.click(location)
```

Now, whenever the "OK" button is on your screen, PyAutoGUI will click on it

Comment: "right now PyAutoGUI only handles the primary monitor" - from the documentation at https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest